# Could not instantiate class named UIRefreshControl Xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

I am building a RSS feed on a tableview. When i run the app, on my iPhone could run smoothly while in ipad, it crashed and showed "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIRefreshControl'"

I tried to run the app on my ipad simulator, it also could run smoothly. May I know what is the problem for that?

Thanks

Comment: Your iPad is running iOS 6, right?

Comment: first generation ipad. On 5.1.1,

Comment: Just found this related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027250/subclassing-uirefreshcontrol-but-still-supporting-ios-5-1 Not sure how to try it, since I am not intentionally calling UIRefreshControl, but it may provide help for others with the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIRefreshControl` only exists on iOS 6.  So if your iPad is running 5.1.1, you won't be able to use `UIRefreshControl`, because `UIRefreshControl` did not exist in iOS 5.1.1.  So when the nib decoding happens, the decoder finds `"UIRefreshControl"`, it doesn't know what to do with it, and it crashes.

Comment: There must be something we can change in the environment or the compiler or the code that will avoid this Error.
App developers still need to support the several hundred thousand iPad-1 customers out there.

Comment: @SidWyckoff it's easy: `if ([UIRefreshControl class] != nil) { /* add iOS 6's pull to refresh */ } else { /* use your own pull to refresh */ }`

Answer (score 5):

In your storyboard, click on the tableview and go to the Attribute Inspector. Under the section "TableView Controller" there is a selection window for "Refreshing" that can be set to disabled. When I built for my iPad-1, running iOS 5.1 I got an empty tableView instead of the error, 'Could not instantiate class named UIRefreshControl'. This was to be expected since I haven't populated the device with files to select, yet.